# FFMpeg Image2Pipe VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, stdin

i m trying to pipe image from my code to ffmpeg.. i am using flowing code:

but it does not working, produced video is not playable :(

```
    Dim proc As Process = New Process()
    Dim objStream As System.IO.Stream
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = strAPPPath & "\ffmpeg.exe"
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f image2pipe -i pipe:.bmp -crf 25.0 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc -vf scale=1280:720 -ar 48000 -b:a 160k -coder 1 -rc_lookahead 60 -threads 0 -an out_vid.mp4"
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    proc.Start()
    objStream = proc.StandardInput.BaseStream
    For i As Integer = 0 To 75 - 1
        Using img As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile(strAPPPath & "\IMG\1033_WebImage.jpg")
            img.Save(objStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End Using
        objStream.Flush()
    Next
    objStream.Close()
    proc.WaitForExit()
```

so, what i am missing here?

best regards

Comment: "Not working" has no meaning. Can you expand? Do you get any error or warning from FFMPEG?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image loop after you start the `Process`?

Comment: sir, it just create a output file with that name and file size is only 262 byte :(,

Comment: Although I've used FFMPEG extensively, I've never 'piped' it. However, are you sure this is correct >>> `-i pipe:.bmp` ?